# I am not able to scan Maxicode Barcode Zxing Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, zxing, zxing.net

I have the next code:

```
 MobileBarcodeScanningOptions options = new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
        options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
            ZXing.BarcodeFormat.MAXICODE
        };
        options.TryHarder = true;

        var scannerPage = new ZXingScannerPage(options);

        scannerPage.Title = "Lector de QR";
        scannerPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            scannerPage.IsScanning = false;
            Console.WriteLine(result.Text);
       }
```

Never enters the  scannerPage.OnScanResult function when I'm try to read a Maxicode Barcode

Comment: How are you connecting to the scanner (USB, Ethernet, other).  What driver are you using in the interface.  Often issues like this you installed the standard Microsoft driver instead of the Vendor Driver.  Do you have vendor software that works?  I always recommend using a vendor application first before trying a c# application.  Working with vendor software eliminate lots of reason for issue like cabling and driver.

Comment: Thanks, this code if for run in Android mobile using the phone camera

Comment: Are you running 1.4.7.1? https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/CHANGES.md